# swift 4.0 cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type (() -> Void)?

Tags: ios11, swift4

I was migrating my project to swift 3.0 - 4.0 using Xcode 9 beta 5 but got below error message.
[image]

Please help out if any one come across this problem.

```
@IBAction func refreshToLoadData() {
        if !isDataPulled {
            if !DemoModeManager.shared.isReachable {
                self.showNetworkErrorWithCallback(screen: "Load Bags Info".localize(), okHandler: { (inner2) in do
                {
                    self.okClick()
                    }})
            } else {
                self.getDataForBags()
            }
        } else {
            self.endRefreshing()
            self.bagsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


   func showNetworkErrorWithCallback(screen: String, okHandler: (() -> Void)?) {
        let okAction = AlertAction("OK".localize(), { (okAction) in
            okHandler?()
        })
        showAlert(networkErrorTitle, message: networkErrorMessageFormat, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert, animated: false, alertCompletion:nil, cancelAction: nil, otherActions: okAction)
    }
```

Comment: Please include codes as text. But as far as I can see, your `okHandler` is declared as `(() -> Void)?`, ignoring Optional, a closure type which takes no arguments. Why are you putting an argument `(inner2)` in the closure?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are passing a closure with one argument for the closure parameter with no argument.

Just remove the useless arguments:

```
@IBAction func refreshToLoadData() {
    if !isDataPulled {
        if !DemoModeManager.shared.isReachable {
            self.showNetworkErrorWithCallback(screen: "Load Bags Info".localize(), okHandler: {
                /* ### Do not put any arguments here" ### */
                do {
                    self.okClick()
                }
            })
        } else {
            self.getDataForBags()
        }
    } else {
        self.endRefreshing()
        self.bagsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

---

In older Swift, Swift accepted a closure with a single argument whose type is `Void` passing as a no-argument closure. But such behavior is removed from Swift 4. And even if it compiles in Swift 3, you should think such code as a super-bad practice.

Do not put an argument when you need to pass a closure with no-arguments.